# Coplanar checker missing a certain case

Tags: c#, geometry

I constructed a small function to check if a group of points are coplanar:

```
public static bool IsCoplanar(Point[] points)
{
    // Ensure there are greater than three points (otherwise always coplanar)
    if (points.Length < 4)
    {
        return true;
    }

    Point pointA = points[0];
    Point pointB = points[1];
    Point pointC = points[2];

    // Calculate the scalar triple product using vectors formed from
    // the first three points and each successive point to check that 
    // the point is on the same plane as the first three.
    Vector vectorBA = pointB - pointA;
    Vector vectorCA = pointC - pointA;

    for (int i = 3; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        Point pointD = points[i];

        Vector vectorDA = pointD - pointA;

        if (!(System.Math.Abs(vectorBA.Dot(vectorCA.Cross(vectorDA))) < Epsilon))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be returning true in the case, for example, starting with 3 coplanar points:

```
(-50, 50, -50)
(-50, -50, -50)
(-50, -50, 50)
```

Which are fine. But if you add:

```
(50, -50, 50)
(50, -50, -50)
```

To the list and run again, it still returns true.

I've been looking at this for ages but haven't been able to spot the problem, does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I could be on the tangent here but if I remember my cross products correctly.. looking at your code: CA cross DA will produce a vector perpendicular to both with most likely non-unit length. The vector BA (used in dot product) is also most likely not unit. The cross product vector maybe in either direction, hence having the dot product be either negative or positive. What you can do is normalize all vectors at play and then check if the absolute value of dot product is close to 1 (+- delta). That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hm, okay. I normalised the vectors. When you say that the absolute value of the dot product do you mean as calculated in my previous solution? Because that still tends towards 0 rather than 1 (although I think you're on to something with the direction of the vectors not being taken into account).

Comment: What are Point, Vector and Epsilon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing obvious about the code jumps out at me, but you might try a slightly different approach.

Given the formula for a plane:

```
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
```

take your first three points, which define a plane, and generate the coefficients `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

For the rest of the points, then check:

```
   Point v;

   float d = A * v.x + B * v.y + C * v.d;
```

`d` is now the distance from that point to the plane, along the plane's normal.

If `d` is less than `D` (the distance of the plane to the origin along its normal), the point is behind the plane (ie, opposite side of the plane from which the normal is pointing). If `d` is greater than `D`, the point is in front of the plane.

if `abs(d - D) < float.Epsilon)`, then the point may safely be assumed to lie in the plane.

**Example** ([from this site](http://www.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/equations.html))

Given points P, Q, R in space, find the equation of the plane through the 3 points.

If `P = (1, 1, 1), Q = (1, 2, 0), R = (-1, 2, 1)`.

We seek the coefficients of an equation ax + by + cz = d, where P, Q and R satisfy the equations, thus:

```
a + b + c = d
a + 2b + 0c = d
-a + 2b + c = d
```

Subtracting the first equation from the second and then adding the first equation to the third, we eliminate a to get

```
b - c = 0
4b + c = 2d
```

Adding the equations gives 5b = 2d, or b = (2/5)d, then solving for c = b = (2/5)d and then a = d - b - c = (1/5)d.

So the equation (with a nonzero constant left in to choose) is `d(1/5)x + d(2/5)y + d(2/5)z = d`, so one choice of constant gives

```
x + 2y + 2z = 5
```

or, `A` = 1, `B` = 2, `C` = 2, and `D` = -5.

Once you have those, checking the rest of the points is simply substituting the point's x,y,z into the plane equation, and comparing the output to the D distance of the plane to the origin.

Note that the coefficients can also be found using a matrix to solve a system of three equations with three unknowns. If you already have a matrix class available, it should be pretty straightforward to use it to find the coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code in C#. Note, operations like Cross and Equal should be class operators, I did not do that. Also, I included edge case testing for things like coincidental points. I.E. what happens if input are non-unique points, like (50,50,50) followed by (50,50,50), your current code fails!

```
public static bool IsCoplanar(MyPoint[] points)
    {
        if (points.Length <= 3)
            return true;

        //input points may be the coincidental/same (edge case),
        //so we first need to loop to find three unique points.
        //the first unique point is by default at position 0,
        //so we will start looking for second at position 1:
        int unique_point2_index = 0;
        int unique_point3_index = 0;
        bool found_point2 = false;
        bool found_point3 = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; ++i )
        {
            if (!found_point2)
            {
                if (!Equals(points[0], points[i]))
                {
                    found_point2 = true;
                    unique_point2_index = i;
                }
            }
            else if (!found_point3)
            {
                if (!Equals(points[0], points[i]) && !Equals(points[unique_point2_index], points[i]))
                {
                    found_point3 = true;
                    unique_point3_index = i;
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        //if we did not find three unique points, then all of the points are coplanar!
        if (!found_point3)
            return true;

        //we found three unique points lets loop through the rest and check if those
        //are also coplanar. We do that as following:
        //First compute the plane normal:
        MyPoint P1 = points[0];
        MyPoint P2 = points[unique_point2_index];
        MyPoint P3 = points[unique_point3_index];
        MyPoint vecP1P2 = Minus(P2, P1); //Should be class operator, P2 - P1
        MyPoint vecP1P3 = Minus(P3, P1);
        MyPoint normal = Cross(vecP1P2, vecP1P3);

        //Secondly, for the remainder of points, we compute
        //a vector from P1 to each point,
        //and take the dot product with the normal.
        //This should be zero (+- epsilon) for coplanar points
        for (int i = unique_point3_index + 1; i < points.Length; ++i)
        {
            MyPoint testVec = Minus(points[i], P1);
            double dot = Dot(testVec, normal);
            //include error boundary for double precision
            if (Math.Abs(dot) > 0.000001)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```